# SQL Referencing Foreign Key in Create Table Error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Would love some help with this script... All goes well with: creating the database and creating Catergory, Product_Has_Suppiers, and Product tables. When I try to execute Suppliers 'create table' statement it returns a 1215 error 'cannot add foreign key restraint'.

```
-- Create database
Create database if not exists FinalExam;

-- Use Database
Use FinalExamReview;

-- Create table
Create table if not exists Category(
Cat_id int primary key,
`name` varchar(50));

Create table if not exists Product_Has_Suppliers(
Product_Product_ID int,
Suppliers_Supplier_Code int,
Constraint PHS_Keys Primary key (Product_Product_ID, 
Suppliers_Supplier_Code));

Create table if not exists Product(
Product_ID int auto_increment,
`Name` varchar(25) not null,
Price decimal(4,2) not null, 
decription varchar(45),
last_update timestamp not null, 
Category_Cat_ID int,
Foreign key (Category_Cat_ID) References Category(Cat_ID),
Foreign key (Product_ID) References 
Product_Has_Suppliers(Product_Product_ID));

Create table if not exists Suppliers(
Supplier_Code int auto_increment,
`Name` varchar(45),
city varchar(25),
state char(2),
foreign key (Supplier_Code) References 
product_has_suppliers(suppliers_supplier_code));
```

Comment: You have a typo in your reference to the column. It should be `Suppliers_Supplier_Code` not `suppliers_suppier_code`

Comment: ahh yes I see that I think that happened when copy/pasting over to stackoverflow... I have no typo on workbench and it still won't execute

Comment: Aren't you suppose to add the foreign key on the `Product_Has_Suppliers` table instead of `Suppliers`?

Comment: Same thing with your `Product` table.  The foreign key should be at `Product_Has_Suppliers`.  Foreign keys should be at the many side of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes your errors:

```
Create table if not exists Categories (
    category_id int primary key,
    name varchar(50)
);

Create table if not exists Products (
    Product_ID int auto_increment primary key,
    Name varchar(25) not null,
    Price decimal(4,2) not null, 
    decription varchar(45),
    last_update timestamp not null, 
    category_id int,
    Foreign key (category_id) References Categories(category_id)
);

Create table if not exists Suppliers (
    Supplier_Id int auto_increment primary key,
    Name varchar(45),
    city varchar(25),
    state char(2)
);

Create table if not exists Product_Has_Suppliers(
    Product_ID int,
    Supplier_Id int,
    Constraint PHS_Keys Primary key (Product_ID, 
Supplier_Code),
     Foreign key (Product_ID) References 
Products(Product_ID),
     foreign key (Supplier_Id) References 
Suppliers(Supplier_Id)
);
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd7a1b).

What don't you seem to be understanding?

First, `Suppliers` and `Products` are *entities*.  Entities have primary keys, typically the auto-incremented value.  You were defining these columns as foreign keys.  But the primary key is what uniquely identifies each row.

Second, `Product_Has_Suppliers` is a *junction* table (aka "association" table).  It links the two tables with a many-to-many relationship (products have multiple suppliers, suppliers supply multiple products.  It should have a *foreign key* relationship to the other tables.

While I was at it, I made some other changes that I consider best practices:

- The table names are all plural (they are buckets for the entities in them and there should be more than one).
- The primary key is the singular of the table name followed by `_id`.
- The foreign keys have the same name as the primary key.  This is a big convenience so you can use the `using` clause -- for instance.

If you follow these rules, then the code is self-documenting.  You can look at a table and just by the names know what the foreign keys are referring to.

Comment: Fascinating it does fix my errors... anyway you can explain to me why this works I really do want to learn why this happens?

Comment: Thank you this helps me a lot I understand now